# .NET6 app ignores Accept-Language and always uses Regional settings of IIS ApplicationPoolIdentity user

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

I am struggling to get working Localization (only decimal separators and calendar format - not language specific strings) in my .NET6 Razor app based on currently logged in user, app is using Windows authentication and is deployed on IIS.

In my `startup.cs` I have

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

And I can see supported Cultures while debugging on my local machine, which are my local Regional settings not related to locales sent in request via `Accept-Language`
[image]

[image]

In app for `@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture/@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`

[image]

But `Accepted-Language` is only `en-US`

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,cs;q=0.8
```

Same thing happens when app is deployed to IIS Application pool. System user which is set in Identity has it's own Regional settings and these are used for all incoming requests, and `Accept-Language` is ignored.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion how I could format numbers, dates,... based on client's `Accept-Language` and their specific regional settings?

**Edit**: Following suggested link from @Rena tried to play with it more, but without success, client supported Formats are ignored, and it is using only Formatting available for Identity user on IIS.
Here is screenshot from IIS, please note that "Welcome screen" settings are applied to system accounts as well.

[image]

Now if I visit my site hosted on this IIS I will get formatting `en-GB`
[image]
even tho I have locale on client computer set to Czech.

[image]

Comment: Hi @scetu, did you try to add the language and set Language Preferences, refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-accept-language-http-header-in-ie

Comment: Hi @Rena I've edited my question, this link was helpful, but does not solve the issue. Client Region is still ignored and region which is set on IIS is used instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was just mine misunderstood how Globalization works.
In order to not use set locale on IIS app needs to have defined Supported Cultures in `Startup.cs`

```
    var supportedCultures = new[] { 
        new CultureInfo("cs-CZ"), 
        new CultureInfo("fi-FI"), 
        new CultureInfo("de-DE"), 
        new CultureInfo("ro-RO"), 
        new CultureInfo("pl-PL") 
    };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("cs-CZ"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    });
```

Then if user's locale is found in Supported Locales this locale is used, otherwise app falls back to set IIS locale.

Comment: For anyone else struggling [Look here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample) for the Microsoft samples of how to setup localization in .NET Core. There's a folder for each version of .NET core. Take note of the calls and the order that they appear and replicate it in your application.